# PyCharm string replaceing "\'"

Tags: python, pycharm

I have traceback message like:

```
_str = ['exec(\'g.\'+option_val+\'=\'+option_val+\'()\')\n', '  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>\n', '  File "/home/nazariy/git/investment-tools/app/core/utilities/dbmonet.py", line 16, in __init__\n    raise ValueError(\'Could not connect to the MonetDB database\')\n', 'ValueError: Could not connect to the MonetDB database\n']
```

I am trying to replace every \' occurence with " in Pycharm:

```
_str = [str_.replace("\'",'"') for str_ in _str]
```

the above does not work, it splits every single character for some reason. But the above does work in jupyter qtconsole...

I also tried escaping the escape character in Pycharm:

```
_str = [str_.replace("\\'",'"') for str_ in _str]
```

also does not work...

any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is the code snippet that generates the traceback:

```
import sys, traceback
exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
pretty_traceback = repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
#print("---- All the items ---")
#for i, x in enumerate(pretty_traceback): print(str(i) + ": "+(x))
print("------------------------- before pretty -----------------------")
pretty_traceback = [i.replace(r"\'", '"') for i in pretty_traceback]
print(pretty_traceback)
print("------------------------ pretty escape -------------------")
pretty_traceback = [i.replace(r"\n", "") for i in pretty_traceback]
print(pretty_traceback)
print("------------------------ pretty replace -------------------")
pretty_traceback = ["<p>"+_str+"</p>"       for _str in pretty_traceback]
print(pretty_traceback)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex

**Ex:**

```
import re
_str = ['exec(\'g.\'+option_val+\'=\'+option_val+\'()\')\n', '  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>\n', '  File "/home/nazariy/git/investment-tools/app/core/utilities/dbmonet.py", line 16, in __init__\n    raise ValueError(\'Could not connect to the MonetDB database\')\n', 'ValueError: Could not connect to the MonetDB database\n']
_str = [re.sub(r"\'", '"', i) for i in _str]
print(_str)
```

**Output:**

```
['exec("g."+option_val+"="+option_val+"()")\n', '  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>\n', '  File "/home/nazariy/git/investment-tools/app/core/utilities/dbmonet.py", line 16, in __init__\n    raise ValueError("Could not connect to the MonetDB database")\n', 'ValueError: Could not connect to the MonetDB database\n']
```

Comment: hmm... that still splits every character

Comment: snippet: ['n', 'a', 'z', 'a', 'r', 'i', 'y'', ',', ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'o', 't', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'D', 'B', ' ', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', 'b', 'a', 's', 'e', '\\', "'", ')', '\\', 'n', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'V', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'E', 'r', 'r', 'o', 'r', ':', ' ', 'C', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'n', 'e', 't', 'D', 'B', ' ', 'd', 'a', 't', 'a', 'b', 'a', 's', 'e', '\\', 'n', "'", ']']

Comment: Using your example I am getting the result I posted in solution.

Comment: I have added the code snippet that generates the traceback, maybe it will shed some light for you.

Comment: but look at your output, you still have:  "(\'Could not connect to the MonetDB database\')", i.e. \'

Comment: in the later element, not in the initial one O_o

Comment: Updated snippet to use re module.